# Navbar Not changing color

Tags: html, css, uikit, navbar

I don't understand why my navbar is not changing color despite the fact that I added CSS to modify it. This is something so simple but it's really bothering me because it is not working as it should.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-top">
   <nav class="uk-navbar" id="navBar">
      <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
          <li class="uk-active"><a href="">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
#navBar {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work OK here : https://jsfiddle.net/eu9oo63p/ I would assume that you have other CSS that is affecting the navbar. You may need to post the full HTML and full CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The css property is most probably overridden by another property which targets the same element too either because:

**A.** The new css property is preceding the older one, or

**B.** You are not specific enough with the css selector `#navbar`.

**Solution for A:**

Make sure this property:

```
#navBar {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

is **below** all other css properties and make sure the css file which has the above property is **below** other css files too and see if that helps.

---

**Solution for B:**

If that didn't help, then there's a probability that the css selector is not specific enough.

In order to override the other `background-color` property, your new selector `#navbar` needs to be more specific than the other selector when targeting the `navbar` element.

This can be done by including the parent divs class/id too in the selector like this:

```
.uk-container.uk-container-center.uk-margin-top #navBar {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

**N.B.** Try adding the above css property without the `!important` tag first and if it doesn't seem to work, then try adding the above along with the `!important` tag.

---

### Regarding **CSS SPECIFICITY**, read this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-top">
   <nav class="uk-navbar" id="navBar">
      <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
          <li class="uk-active"><a href="">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Seems like your code is working fine even if you don't add !important. There must be something in your code, which is overriding the nav color (also with !important).